# AngularJS - Angular way of binding on parent to trigger child

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
```

and I have two directives, one for `parent` and one for `child`. Now, on an event (say click) on `parent`, I want something to happen on `child` (say gets a click).

The jQuery way of doing this would be:

```
app.directive('parent', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.bind('click', function()
            {
                element.find('.child').click();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And if I am not mistaking, the Angular way would be to change a scope in `parent`, and `$watch` for it in child:

```
app.directive('parent', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.childEvent = false; 

            element.bind('click', function()
            {
                scope.childEvent = true;
            });
        }
    }
}   

app.directive('child', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch('childEvent', function(value)
            {
                if (value) element.click();
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me which method is better, and why? The first method is for sure shorter, but  it seems everyone says that the Angular way is the second method (so that I don't use jQuery). I want to know what problems could arise if I use the jQuery way.

Comment: If parent/child always go in pairs, the Angular way would be to use a single directive and drop all the $watch and click listeners and manipulate the scope variables directly. Of course, in some cases that might not be possible, but it usually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the second variant is "the angular way" of solving your problem. This one is (if you look from the view of an angular developer) the solution which gets along without manipulating the DOM manualy. In my opinion that's the main idea of AngularJS: stop manipulating the DOM manualy - let Angular do that for you.